# Recurring Payment Reminder email

Tags: emails

I am selling some monthly basis services like website hosting. And I like to get prepaid payment for every month. So, how do I send email to my clients for notification by email to give payment for coming recurring date?

For example - A client purchase a digital service from our website in 5th of Jan. Next recurring payment date should be 5th Feb. So, I like to send recurring payment reminder before 15 days, then before 10 days (if not paid), then before 5 days (if not paid), then in the recurring date i.e. in 5th Feb.

I have install drupal 7, commerce recurring framework module, rules, rules scheduler. Currently I am stuck with how to send periodic email to my client for recurring date, after they have initially pay for the services?

Is this module is perfect for this - https://www.drupal.org/project/datereminder​. I think this module - https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_recurring is not sending email reminders. Specially I am looking for email reminders which will work with commerce recurring framework.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: Consider editing your question to provide more details about (a) how you have configured your clients to be eMailed (content types, etc), (b) if you're using something like the commerce module (or not) and (c) what you have done/tried so far (and where you got stuck). Not doing so will probably soon result in your question being put on hold and/or closed. Just a suggestion, ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

[How to Send Follow-Up Emails Using Rules Scheduler in Drupal 7 ?](http://www.webwash.net/tutorials/how-send-follow-emails-using-rules-scheduler-drupal-7)